# Tally ERP 9 is very slow on Ubuntu

Tags: wine

We have installed Tally ERP 9 software on Ubuntu 12.04 using Wine and it is widely used in India for accounting activities but the software is responding very slowly.

If someone can suggest any workaround for this, it would really be appreciated.

Comment: what is the server running on this erp?

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual machine, i.e. virtualbox or Vmware.

Here is a link that has a complete "How To" which will show you how to install and configure VIrtual Box on Ubuntu.

[Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box-in-ubuntu-12-04/187442#187442)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machine is nice option but I have faced problems working that solution.
VirtualBox may limit your screen size. Plus as you keep feeding data in Tally, by the end of half financial year, it becomes heavy and might take minutes to load. If Windows is installed in VirtualBox or VMware.

Solutions which worked well is DUAL-BOOT.
You can keep dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows.

In which windows will be dedicated for Tally ERP 9 and Ubuntu for rest of the work.