# Install windows 7 through virtual box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, system-installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to install Windows 7 on my system from a CD through VirtualBox. I searched the detailed tutorials through google but I did not find one that worked.

So can some one kindly share any detailed tutorial or link which will really help me out.

Comment: Except the Oracle product doesn't install. It downloads and when I click install the install screen disappears and nothing happens.

Answer (score 50):

Go to their website:

https://www.virtualbox.org/

[image]

Then choose linux host

[image]

see 12.04 then choose either 32 bit or 64 bit

[image]

wait until download finishes

[image]

install virtualbox by clicking on the downloaded file

After that launch the program

[image]

Click on New and a window will show up

Choose a name and a version

[image]

click next

Now choose the amount of Ram. Red is danger. Green is OK

[image]

click Next

choose create virtual Drive

[image]

click create and a new windows will show up

Choose the 1st option and click next

Now either choose fixed or dynamically. I prefer dynamical so you can change the size later

[image]

Click next

Now choose the amount you want to allocate for your harddisk give it a name and click create

[image]

Now we need to configure it so Click on settings

[image]

Ignore the error and click OK

[image]

choose storage on the left panel and choose the CD icon that says Empty

[image]

Now Click on the CD icon on the far right and choose DVD/CD and Click OK

[image]

Now Click on the Start Button and boot from your CD

[image]

Do not forget to insert your CD

Comment: I don't think its necessary to insert the CD. You can click on that green + button on the storage settings and show where the ISO file is.

Comment: Using the `virtualbox` package from the repositories should do the job as well, if you hesitate to download the latest version from their homepage.

Answer (score 4):

It may be convenient to use virtual machines you download and manage locally from Microsoft:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/linux/

Comment: The question is about installing Windows 7. Why would you link to a Virtual-Image  meant to test Edge and IE?

Comment: because this are normall VM on which you can install whatever you need without need to buy windows or search some torrents

Comment: "Please note that these virtual machines expire after 90 days. We recommend setting a snapshot when you first install the virtual machine which you can roll back to later." Not normal VM.

Comment: possibly now moved to: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

- http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-on-virtualbox/ (Kinda old, but the process is the same.)
- http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/how-to-install-windows-7-in-virtualbox-guide-hatryst (newer one)
- http://nachiket.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/how-to-install-windows-7-on-virtualbox/ (kinda old too)
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoSebbqBQQo ( A youtube video. Kinda old too, but still)