# How do I use Virtualbox and install Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install windows 7 through virtual box in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box-in-ubuntu-12-04)

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Virtualbox. I am new to Virtualbox and I am stuck on how to put on windows 7 on it.

I don't get how to do: CD/DVD Drive.

Comment: Do you have a legal ISO or a disk from where to install Windows from?

Comment: No I don't, why?

Comment: @luke, you will need a Legal Windows ISO or DVD and a Windows license to run Windows in VirtualBox, just like on a physical machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow the steps given below;

- Open virtual box from unity dash.
- Once the virtual box window comes up, click on "New"
- Give a name for your OS, preferably "windows 7". It should automatically change the version to "windows 7". Click Next.
- Select a memory size, preferably "1024 MB" . Click Next.
- Choose the hard drive. Select "create a virtual hard drive now". Click Next.
- Choose hard drive file type. I personally prefer "VDI" or "VMDK". Click Next.
- Choose the storage type on physical hard drive. I prefer "Dynamically allocated". Click Next.
- In file location n size choose the defaults. Click Next.
- Now it'll show you in the oracle VM virtual box manager.
- Now click on START.
- Choose the boot medium either CD/DVD ROM(which is default) or browse to an iso file.

From then onwards its just like installing on a physical machine.

Comment: But do you need a blank CD/DVD or a windows CD?

Comment: You'll need a windows CD

Comment: Is it possible to install windows from a CD/DVD that is NOT bootable?

Answer (score 1):

First make a new machine with your desired settings. Then boot the empty machine, open up Devices -> CD / DVD Devices and select your DVD drive with the disk in it. If you need more help let me know.

[image: http://i46.tinypic.com/2eam25w.jpg]

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @luke: I presume he means just what he said. Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Where is devices, because I can't see it.

Comment: @luke have you made a new machine yet?

Comment: Yes I have, I am on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @luke in the screenshot, GNOME3 is shown, which has the menus on the application's window. If you are using Unity, look at the top of the screen where it says VirtualBox, move your mouse just to the right of that and you should see the menus appear, click on Devices there.

Comment: ok now i get it

Answer (score 1):

In Virtualbox, after you have setup the machine you have two options.

1. Use your host DVD drive and put Windows 7 DVD in the drive
2. Use an .iso image as your boot DVD

[image]

I usually use an .iso image, but if you have a DVD that is just as easy. Just use 'Host Drive..."