# Error trying to make USB drive into bootable host drive in Virtualbox

Tags: installation, boot, usb, virtualbox, unetbootin

I want to install Ubuntu as guest OS on Win7 on Virtualbox.  When i try to designate my USB drive as the host drive for installation purposes, it gives me this error:

Result Code: 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: 
Medium
Interface: 
IMedium {29989373-b111-4654-8493-2e1176cba890}
Callee: 
IVirtualBox {3b2f08eb-b810-4715-bee0-bb06b9880ad2}
Callee RC: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

Unetbootin won't let me make a CD disc to boot from so i'm left with my USB drive which has the ISO on it.  Thx in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Box does not allow booting from USB. To install Ubuntu you need to directly mount the downloaded Ubuntu .iso file as a **virtual** CD drive in Virtual Box Manager. There is no need to make a bootable USB drive.

Also see:

- [Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Thx, that was what i had to do.  It worked.