# Install a guest Win10 in VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04 from USB

Tags: boot, usb, virtualbox, 20.04

I am running VirtualBox 6.1.6_Ubuntu r137129 under Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a USB stick with a Win10 installer created from within Win10.
I want to create a VM and install Win10 from the USB.

**How can I do that?**
When trying, I get an error, see below.

[Install a guest Win10 in VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04 from ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237632/install-a-guest-win10-in-virtualbox-in-ubuntu-20-04-from-iso?noredirect=1#comment2084426_1237632)
is a "companion", but different, question.

---

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/267682/is-it-possible-to-install-a-guest-operating-system-from-usb-on-virtualbox) asks something similar, but with much older versions (Virtualbox 4.0.4 Fedora 14), so the question is not exactly the same.
The accepted answer links to [here](http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/), dating back to 2013.
The solution posted:

1. Create a VM access which points to the USB (I could do that)

```
$ sudo vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/VirtualBox_VMs/usb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda1
RAW host disk access VMDK file /home/user1/VirtualBox_VMs/usb.vmdk created successfully.
```

2. In the VM (I had already created it), go to *Settings* -> *Storage* -> *Adds hard disk.* (a small icon to the right of *Controller: SATA*) -> *Add* -> (Navigate to and select the `usb.vmdk` file just created) -> OK.

   Here I get **the error**

```
Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '/home/santiago/VirtualBox_VMs/usb.vmdk' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Result Code: 
VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: 
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
Callee: 
IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
Callee RC: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

---

[Error trying to make USB drive into bootable host drive in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338248/error-trying-to-make-usb-drive-into-bootable-host-drive-in-virtualbox) (also an old question) deals with the same error, but since the guest OS is Ubuntu it has the option of mounting the `.iso` image, which apparently solves the issue.
I do not have that option, I have to create a `RAW host disk access` instead.

[Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)
provides the same solution (`.iso` file).

---

**Related**:

[Cannot run native Ubuntu in virtualbox with a vmdk created using the createrawvmdk command with partitions specified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78902/cannot-run-native-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-with-a-vmdk-created-using-the-createrawvm)

[installing an os from a usb](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=78791)

[How to Boot From a USB Drive in VirtualBox](https://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/)

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtualbox%20create%20virtual%20machine%20from%20usb%20installer)

Comment: It is probably easier to boot the virtual machine directly from the Windows 10 iso file, seen as a DVD disk, and then install Windows 10 (to a 'virtual hard disk drive').

Answer (score 0):

With the command you refer in your point 1) you create a `raw vmdk` device who points to the `/dev/sda1` partition. However, when you try to access it you get a permission error. So my guess is that, although you have the right permissions on the `usb.vmdk` file you just created, you probably don't have read/write access to the raw partition device, which is where VirtualBox ultimately goes.

Try `ls -l /dev/sda*` and check the permissions. As you will use this `raw vmdk` device solely for installation purposes, I suggest to temporarily allow access to everyone to this device: `chmod a+rw /dev/sda1`.

I just had this identical problem and that solved the error for me.

Comment: As I could not solve this in time, I will try this solution whenever the need shows up again. Thanks