# Install a guest Win10 in VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04 from ISO

Tags: boot, virtualbox, windows-10, 20.04, iso

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-10-install-virtualbox/) (and posted many places else in various forms, [[1](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-10-install-virtualbox/)](https://askubuntu.com/a/187442/226614)) to boot from an iso image of Win10 under VBox in Ubuntu 20.04.

[image]

I get `Fatal: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted`

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Notes:

1. I actually posted first [Install a guest Win10 in VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04 from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237507/install-a-guest-win10-in-virtualbox-in-ubuntu-20-04-from-usb).
   Since the difference between booting from a USB installer or an `.iso` image installer may be significant, I later changed the title of the other question to specifically address the USB case, and this one to address the `.iso` image case.
2. I managed to import the `ova` image obtained [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), `MSEdge - Win10.ova`, but it is not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install a guest Win10 in VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04 from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237507/install-a-guest-win10-in-virtualbox-in-ubuntu-20-04-from-usb)

Comment: @Pilot6 - No, it does not. I actually posted first that other question. Since the difference between booting from a USB installer or an iso image installer may be significant, I later changed the title of the other question to specifically address the USB case, and this one to address the iso image case.

Comment: Normally after the Create button I press Start and get an option to select the ISO from there. I never go to the Storage settings you show.