# how to install Windows XP guest in virtualbox with Ubuntu 12.04 host

Tags: virtualbox

where in virtualbox do you install Windows XP guest with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as host.

Comment: Have you tried? It should work just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install windows 7 through virtual box](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new virtual machine, set the type to Windows XP, add a virtual harddisk (type: IDE is recommended), attach a Windows XP install ISO to the guest CD drive, start the machine. Installation will run normally inside the guest.
After the OS is installed, it is recommended to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions inside the guest VM.

Alternately, if you're looking to test old IE versions, you could download pre-made virtual machines from http://modern.ie/

Comment: Note: the method in first paragraph requires a valid WinXP license; whereas the images from modern.ie work out of the box, but they are time-limited (and released under a license that's even more restrictive than WinXP's).