# Running windows 8.1 on virtualbox whils on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux. I am currently dual-booting windows 8.1 and Ubuntu and I just downloaded Virtualbox. I am wondering if it is possible to run my Windows 8.1 OS with all of my previous files on it via Virtualbox while I'm on Linux (Ubuntu). If it is possible, how would I go about doing this? Also, is this a good idea?

Comment: No, you cannot boot Windows installed on hard disk directly from Virtual Box, you will have to create a *virtual disk image* using VirtualBox, then install Windows into that disk and then boot Windows from VirtualBox.
[Check this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)