# Successful dual boot. How do I lauch Windows from within Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, virtualhost

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 15.10 side by side with Windows 7 on a brand new Dell Latitude E7450. Seamless, worked out of the tin, as expected.

Have successfully booted into both OSes. Excellent.

Want to use Ubuntu as my primary, as I feel more comfortable in it, but will need Windows for various work related bits and bobs (Outlook, specialised software).

How can I boot into the Windows partition from within the Ubuntu partition? Do I just VM it? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As simple you can access windows files in Ubuntu. but you cant load it inside Ubuntu. To load the  windows you have to restart and log in to system.

Or else

you have to try [virtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to install and run windows as virtual

> [Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I'd prefer to just boot into the system that's already there, while in Ubuntu. Rather than either of these suggestions ("boot into windows" or "install new windows via VM")