# Installing Windows 7 on Ubuntu via USB (without boot screen available!)

Tags: boot, usb, windows, wine, bios

I have this nagging issue with my laptop. I have been googeling and searching for an answer but with no luck. I am currently using it right now on Ubuntu 15.10 but I would like to switch to Windows 7.

I have the iso on the USB ready to go and everything. But the problem is that my screen is broken so I can only use the laptop via the HDMI. Also, my HP Pavillion 15 Sleekbook cannot display the BIOS via the HDMI but only by my primary screen. I even forced my HDMI-screen to become the primary one by removing my laptop screen.

For the last couple of days I have tried to use BIOS screenshots and blindly pressing keystrokes so my Windows can install with no luck.. And there is nothing wrong with the USB since it works on my other laptops and the laptop itself is okay with bootable USB because that is how I installed Ubuntu in the first place.

So my question is: **Is there ANY way for me to install Windows through Ubuntu, without using the BIOS screen?**

*PS. I really love my Ubuntu^^, but I miss playing games on my Windows :)
PS.2. I even installed Wine and tried to open the .exe installation file of Windows. When I press "Install" a message comes up and says I dont have enough space on my boot device.*

Please help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what you're asking for is a software solution to a hardware problem, and that is hardly ever possible...  **:-(**

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐq ɹW  Turns out it is possible in this case.

Comment: Close voters please try to refrain from piling on.

Comment: **Close vote retracted! Answer upvoted!**  @ElderGeek

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW Where there is a will there's a way. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
Is there ANY way for me to install Windows through Ubuntu, without using the BIOS screen?
```

**Yes:** Install virtualbox with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`
under Ubuntu and [Install Windows 7 in a Virtual Machine under virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this tutorial to boot windows from a vhd;
http://developers-club.com/posts/228641/

Download virtualbox to create a vhd, modify /boot/bcd and edit grub.