# Problems with my 3G serial modem

Tags: networking, usb-modem, modem, 3g, serial-port

I'm using a PC with an internal 3G serial modem. The computer is from work, so i asked for specifications and they told me that the name of the modem is:

> Cinterion EGS5

I've been googling for further information, but i was not able to find anything else about it.

My problem here is the next:
Im using lUbuntu 16.04 and when i try to insert the 3G SIM card in the slot, the OS doesn't seem to recognize the modem or the connection.
I would like to repair this and connect the computer via 3G.

I wish i could be more specific, I'm sorry.

EDIT 1:
I have the modem inside this PC, it worked correctly when I had Windows installed in it, but when I installed Lubuntu 16.04, the OS doesn't recognize it as a modem. I have other computers like this one, but with a USB modem instead of the serial modem, and when I click in the connection options, they recognize the 3G modem and show up the connector to connect through the 3G card, instead of connecting via Ethernet.

This is the exit of ModemManager`mmcli -L`:

> No modems were found

This is the exit of `sudo lshw -C network`:

`*-network

       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp1s0
       Version: 06
       Seriennummer: 00:19:99:c0:fd:2f
       Größe: 100Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=10.1.33.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:24 ioport:e000(Größe=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff`

Thanks

Comment: It's a custom PC that we use in this company, more a desktop computer than a laptop. I don't really know the architecture of the computer, sorry

Comment: The thing is that I have tested it in Windows without a problem, but with Lubuntu, I can't get it to work.

Comment: I have updated the info @ElderGeek, i hope this is helpful

Comment: No, as I anticipated on the other hand, not so much. You might however find [this useful](http://www.esea.cz/support/cinterion/egs5/wm_java_user_guide_v19.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing that device [appears to require Windows](http://www.esea.cz/support/cinterion/egs5/wm_java_user_guide_v19.pdf). If I had one available for testing and a system that would accept it, I would try [installing the provided software under wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games) and when that likely failed, I would either attempt the installation on a [Windows VM running under virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box) or simply [dual-boot Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) and install the required software under Windows.

Sources:

http://www.esea.cz/support/cinterion/egs5/wm_java_user_guide_v19.pdf

[How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

[Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

[How can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)