# How to Run Windows 07 in Ubuntu using chroot?

Tags: chroot

Is there any way to make any Windows-OS run in Ubuntu using the chroot-jail or chroot ?

Edit the question as you feel is necessary, typed Windows 07 there as an example and as its a truly good OS.

Comment: It's not possible to run an OS based on a different kernel in a chroot.

Comment: @muru So why not posting this as an answer?

Comment: @Bruni because it seems to me that OP doesn't know what they want (or they don't know what a chroot is)

Comment: @muru OP indeed does not seem to know what a chroot is, but imho that does not disqualify them from getting an answer maybe including a link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with chroot, in order to run Windows on Linux you would need to run a virtual machine using software like VirtualBox.  Please see [Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Comment: The Program I have does not work with Virtual Box thou windows 07 can be installed in it. Am not able to install Windows 07 directly thou due to sata driver problems.