# VirtualBox - FATAL: No bootable medium found! No solution

Tags: virtualbox

I am a user on Ubuntu 14.04. Sorry if this is not the topic, but in VirtualBox there is the following error (which I know was already asked:)

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted
```

No solutions on the web work for me. Can anyone give a solution that really works? Because I have to run Windows 1 for emulation and testing.

I am an advanced Linux user.

-linuhackz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)

Comment: Is this error showing when you are trying to boot a windows guest in a vb installation on ubuntu? In other words, is the windows boot process throwing this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Comment: Not a duplicate of Install windows 7 through virtual box