# Whats the procedure for installing Windows as a Virtualbox instance?

Tags: virtualbox

Of particular trouble to me is getting the USB drivers to cooperate. USB 3.0

USB stick version of windows 10 home. I think I do have the right extension pack although there may be more steps to implementing that than I am aware of.

Comment: Can you clarify your question

Comment: You do not need an USB drive for installing Windows as a guest OS in VirtualBox. Just use the ISO file and mount it as a virtual CD. Extension pack is only needed for using USB3.0 in a Windows VM. Note that installation guides for Windows are beyond the scope of this site. Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box

Comment: I don't have the ISO file. I have a thumb drive for a licensed seat of Windows Home. It came that way.  Is it possible to use my license on the ISO?  I'm fairly ignorant with Windows being primarily a Linux guy.

Comment: For another $50 I was able to find a 240 Gb drive. So I did it as a dual boot.