# How to install Windows 10 on ubuntu 20.04 using VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows-10

How to install Windows 10 on ubuntu 20.04 using VirtualBox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install windows 7 through virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Answer (score 1):

### Some Things to Help Windows Run Better on VirtualBox

**Here are some things that work for me.**

- Create your machine using a fixed size disk
- Allocate more memory
- Install Guest Additions
- Install Extension Packs
- Enable copy paste
- Increase display memory
- Allocate more CPUs
- Ensure Intel VT-x or AMD-V is enabled
- Enable 2D / 3D acceleration
- Suspend instead of shutting down
- Use the Intel PRO/1000 network drivers if using a network

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know this, but VirtualBox comes with a command called `vboxmanage`.

Here is a script that installs the evaluation copy of Windows 10 Enterprise. There is a link in the comments of the code below where you can download the evaluation ISO.

I just ran this script in order to install Windows 10 Enterprise (Evaluation Copy) on Ubuntu 22.04 using the VirtualBox version 17.0

https://gist.github.com/angstyloop/80cea18f767562351ab5f9917cf3f1ec

```
#!/bin/sh

# create-windows-enterprise-vm-from-iso.sh

# Use VBoxManage to create a VirtualBox VM from an evaluation copy of Windows 10
# Enterprise ISO. 

# Follow the download instructions for your region at
#
# https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-10-enterprise
#

# Create a virtual machine named "windows-10-enterprise-bob" from and ISO

name=windows-10-enterprise-bob

vboxmanage createvm --name $name --ostype Windows10_64 --register --basefolder `pwd`

# Turn on IO APIC
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --ioapic on

# Designate RAM size and video RAM size
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --memory 4096 --vram 128

# Create an internal network interface connected to the internal network named
# RedTeamLab
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --nic1 intnet --intnet1 RedTeamLab

# Put the network interface in promiscuous mode
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --nicpromisc1 allow-all

vboxmanage createhd --filename `pwd`/$name/$name_DISK.vdi --size 60000 --format VDI
vboxmanage storagectl $name --name 'SATA Controller' --add sata --controller IntelAhci 
vboxmanage storageattach $name --storagectl 'SATA Controller' --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium `pwd`/$name/$name_DISK.vdi
vboxmanage storagectl $name --name 'IDE Controller' --add ide --controller PIIX4
vboxmanage storageattach $name --storagectl 'IDE Controller' --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium `pwd`/windows-10-enterprise.iso
vboxmanage modifyvm $name --boot1 dvd --boot2 disk --boot3 none --boot4 none

#vboxmanage startvm $name
```